# "There was a problem communicating with Google server. Try again later."

Tags: google-play-store

[image]

I am unable to login to Google Play Store after I formatted my phone just because of slowness. The error is

> There was a problem communicating with Google server. Try again later.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I've downloaded play store from apk mirror. 
And that's worked.

thanks to team.